# Optimizing unioned inner joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm interested in optimizing the runtime of a query:

```
create temp table table_base as
(
  SELECT table_a.* FROM source_A a
  INNER JOIN
  source_B b
  USING(common_field1)
  WHERE a.field1 = x AND a.field2 = y
) 
UNION
(
  SELECT a.* FROM source_C a
  INNER JOIN
  source_B b
  USING(common_field1)
  WHERE a.field1 = x AND a.field2 = y
) UNION...
```

The first table in each subquery (in this example source_A and source_C) have identical structure, but the largest amount of data. The inner join to source_B is necessary I'm interested in appending a field and removing values not available in source_B's common field.

The query itself does currently run, but I'm wondering if there's a faster way of doing this. I've already placed the WHERE clauses within the subquery as opposed to at the end of the union, but it makes me wonder if it's faster to union/union all first then do a single inner join?

Any help is much appreciated (even if it means that this is somehow the most efficient query structure).

Comment: `table_a`  <-> `source_A a` - typos I assume?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are aiming to remove duplicate rows, use **`UNION ALL`** instead of `UNION`, and it will be massively faster.

And it's typically fastest to apply `WHERE` clauses as early in the process as possible - i.e. like you have it now. Also allows the use of indexes where applicable. Would not be possible if you apply the `WHERE` to the result of the `UNION` / `UNION ALL`.

And do you really mean `INNER JOIN source_B b`? Thereby possibly multiplying rows in `a`? The intention may be (to avoid duplication):

```
SELECT *
FROM   source_A a
WHERE  a.field1 = x
AND    a.field2 = y
AND    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM source_B b WHERE b.common_field1 = a.common_field1)
```

.. likewise for `source_C` ...

The best query really depends on the nature of the relationship between `source_A` and `source_B`, their cardinalities and available indexes.
You might join to filter on the precondition of existence in `source_B`, or to multiply rows, or to retrieve additional columns (you mentioned that).  But the latter does not clarify it all. There is room for interpretation ...

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance one key aspect is to remove non-selected rows out of the way as soon as possible. Having two separate joins is a good choice, since you are forcing the joins to exclude non-matching rows right away.

But first, you'll need to ensure the engine is using the fastest access predicate to filter data from the massive tables `source_A` and `source_C`. For your filtering predicates you are using simple equalities... that's perfect. I would add the following indexes to your tables (if you don't already have them):

```
create index ix1 on source_A (field1, field2);
create index ix2 on source_C (field1, field2);
```

Now, once rows from `source_A` and `source_C` are selected you'll need to access `source_B`. For this task to be fast you'll need to make sure the following index is also present:

```
create index ix3 on source_B (common_field);
```

You also mention that some columns from `source_B` can be used. To make it *marginally* faster you could try a covering index on it. For example if you are using the column `name` from `source_B` I would convert this index to a covering index as in:

```
create index ix3 on source_B (common_field, name); -- added column "name"
```

Finally, once you have these changes in place, you should get an execution plan to see what the SQL optimizer is doing. That never hurts, and will show you in detail if it's choosing the best path or not. Use `EXPLAIN` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
    CREATE TEMP TABLE table_base as
(
  SELECT a.*
  FROM (
    (
      SELECT * FROM source_A WHERE a.field1 = x AND a.field2 = y
    )
    UNION
    (
      SELECT * FROM source_C WHERE a.field1 = x AND a.field2 = y
    )
  ) a
  JOIN source_B b 
  USING(common_field1)
)
```

This way you are doing the WHERE(and reducing the number of records) before the JOIN. This along with indexes added to any columns used for the JOIN that are not would more than likely be your best option

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends on your sorting and distribution. For this query, ideally `source_A` table's sort key is `(x,y)` and all tables' distribution key is `common_field1`. This can make a massive difference in the speed of your query regardless of how it is written.
2. As pointed out above, `UNION ALL` provides a very good boost if you don't have intersections in the UNION sets that you need to deduplicate.
3. I would also try a query without union. Check below:

--

```
SELECT source_A.* 
FROM source_A a
LEFT JOIN source_B b
USING(common_field1)
LEFT JOIN source_C c
USING(common_field1)
WHERE a.field1 = x 
AND a.field2 = y
AND (
    b.id is not null
    or c.id is not null
)
```